# Provisioning profile and push notification certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, provisioning-profile

I've been given a task to (re?)enable push notification for the company iOS app and don't know where to begin.

I learned that provisioning profile contains information on which app services are enabled, so 
I logged into the apple developer center and got to the Certificates,Identifiers & Profiles page, but saw that Development iOS Provisioning Profile was already enabled with Push Notification.

However in the App IDs section, it shows Push Notification as configurable with a yellow dot.

Does this mean that the push notification is no longer working?

If that is the case, would regenerating the push notification certificate fix it? or would I have to create a new provisioning profile as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push certificate had been expired so it required creating a new push certificate. This invalidated provisioning profile with associated app id, so I had to re-generate the provisioning profile as well.

Comment: I just did this and didn't work till I updated both the developer and production push certificates.

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same problem. I had it token care of!

You need to add iOS push certificate！

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action

Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If in the App iD of your App its says **Configurable** then you better start by creating a new certificate, if not then try to get the exact private key of your CSR, your certificate and your `pem` file which you might have used earlier. It would do well to re-configure the entire thing actually, a mismatch between the private key would never allow you to receive the notifications

Comment: I generated a new push certificate, but now my development provisioning profile shows as invalid in the ios dev center, does this mean this has to be recreated as well?